# Restore bson document with insertMany command

Tags: mongodb

I need to restore many collections with many documents in mongodb, but I have only the json documents from it, and I don`t have permission to use the bash to perform mongorestore.

How I can to restore the json documents using only a mongo script (for example, db.collection.insertMany)?

Comment: [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html) is a tool to import JSON documents into collections; this is a OS command line tool. But, if you want to use mongo shell commands you can create JavaScript script files with insert statements with JSON data embedded. See [Write Scripts for the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/). You can post some sample JSON you are trying to use in insert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example run from `Mongo shell`. The books data is JSON and is stored as an array. There are 3 books data:

```
> var booksArr = [
{
        "title" : "To Kill a Mockingbird",
        "author" : "Harper Lee",
        "goodreadsRating" : 4.3,
        "published" : "1960-07-11T00:00:00Z",
        "genres" : [
                "Novel",
                "Domestic Fiction",
                "Legal Story"
        ]
},
{
        "title" : "Hamlet",
        "author" : "Willian Shakespeare",
        "genres" : [
                "Tragedy",
                "Drama"
        ],
        "goodreadsRating" : 4,
        "published" : "1599-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},
{
        "title" : "My Man Jeeves",
        "author" : "P. G. Wodehouse",
        "genres" : [
                "Short story",
                "Humorous Fiction"
        ],
        "goodreadsRating" : 4.1,
        "published" : "1919-05-01T00:00:00Z"
}
];
```

Insert into the `books2` collection, and read the collection to see the inserted documents:

```
> db.books2.insertMany(booksArr);

> db.books2.findOne()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc4dcc9c2ac920e04692774"),
        "title" : "To Kill a Mockingbird",
        "author" : "Harper Lee",
        "goodreadsRating" : 4.3,
        "published" : "1960-07-11T00:00:00Z",
        "genres" : [
                "Novel",
                "Domestic Fiction",
                "Legal Story"
        ]
}
```

Note that `_id` field and values are automatically created. But, you can supply your own in the JSON and these need to be unique for each document within a collection.

See the `published` field, it is a date data stored as string. MongoDB document data has [BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html) data (it is an extended version of JSON). You can convert the string date to `Date` field later (as needed; also see [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)).