# Make a script to create MongoDB collections from Mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Could you please help me out in writing Mongo Shell script to create new collections and indexes to it. Here are some part of the code which i wrote and i need to refactored it.

```
db.createCollection("Dog", { autoIndexId : true});

db.createCollection("Cat", { autoIndexId : true});

db.createCollection("Mouse", { autoIndexId : true});

db.createCollection("Name", { autoIndexId : true});
```

In above code can i write single statement to create multiple collections? and also add multiple indexes to one collection in one go?

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called as "my_scripts.js", with the following commands. This JavaScript defines the data and commands to create two collections (`dogs` and `cats`), their data (documents as JSON) and the indexes (indexes are created on the `name` field of the collection).

**my_scripts.js:**

```
let dogDocs = [
  {
    name: "pooch",
    breed: "poodle",
    weight: "6 lbs"
  },
  {
    name: "mutt",
    breed: "bulldog",
    weight: "10 lbs"
  }
];

let catDocs = [
  {
    name: "minni", 
    breed: "persian",
    color: "white"
  },
  {
    name: "tinkle",
    breed: "bombay",
    color: "black"
  }
];

let dogIndex = { name : 1 };
let catIndex = { name : 1 };

let collInfoObjs = [ 
  { coll: "dogs", data: dogDocs, index: dogIndex }, 
  { coll: "cats", data: catDocs, index: catIndex } 
];

for (obj of collInfoObjs) {
    db[obj.coll].insertMany(obj.data);
    db[obj.coll].createIndex(obj.index);
}
```

**Run the script file:**

From the *mongo shell* run the script as (you can specify the file path with the `load` command):

```
mongo > load("my_script.js");
```

After the script is run, you can use the following commands individually to verify the collections, their documents and the indexes:

```
db.dogs.find();
db.cats.find();
db.dogs.getIndexes();
db.cats.getIndexes();
```

Note that the documents will have a unique `_id` field (of type `ObjectId`) created if you don't supply the `_id` in the input JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo Shell scripts are just JavaScript scripts. You can use regular JavaScript control structures like loops, and string interpolation / string manipulation operations for generating collection names.

I'm guessing it will be

```js
["Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Name"].forEach(function(collName) {
    db.createCollection(collName, {autoIndexId: true});
});
```

Comment: @uttamrao doesn't my post answer your question entirely?

Comment: I was looking for something else

Comment: @uttamrao then i guess you must think about editing your question further

Comment: @uttamrao ah right, sorry, didn't notice the change. I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the *Mongo shell*:

```
> use myNewDB;

> var myCollections = [ "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Name" ];
> myCollections.forEach( collName => db.createCollection( collName, { autoIndexId : true} ) );

// -or-

> [ "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Name" ].forEach( collName => db.createCollection( collName ) );

> show collections
Cat
Dog
Mouse
Name
```

*NOTE:*

`{ autoIndexId : true}` option is *deprecated* since MongoDB version 3.2; it is about creating index on `_id` field. The `_id`'s unique index is mandatory now and is created automatically. So you don't have to specify the option (and cannot specify `false` option; it will give an error).

You can create a detailed script to add indexes after a collection is created, further. See [Write scripts from Mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/).

Comment: You can create JS script(s) to add documents to collections using `insert` methods. Or, even import data into collections from JSON or CSV files using OS command line tool `mongoimport`. Search your favorite topic at [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) for more details.

Comment: See the code in this post, which you can include in your JS script: [Restore bson document with insertMany command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752173/restore-bson-document-with-insertmany-command/58759922#58759922).

Comment: Yes, one for each collection.

Comment: You can put all the statements in a JavaScript file. The statements will execute one after the other. See the link I had provided in the answer: Write scripts from Mongo Shell.

Answer (score -1):

We have a [whole page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) on writing scripts for the shell. Scripts that are executed from a file use a slightly different syntax for creating connections and getting databases e.g.:

Opening connections:

```
new Mongo()
new Mongo(<host>)
new Mongo(<host:port>)
```

Getting a database:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("myDatabase");
```

Comment: The link you provided does not work anymore, please update it. I think it might be https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, there is a new shell since I wrote this post. Your link is right on the money.