# MongoDB Atlas - Create and db from a script

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i'm trying to create collection from a script in mongodb, i found on this link a useful script to do that [Make a script to create MongoDB collections from Mongo shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758740/make-a-script-to-create-mongodb-collections-from-mongo-shell) (thanks for that script).

I'm using now this kind of script and it work fine:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('emanueledb');
var collectionList = ["collection1", "collection2", "collection3"]
collectionList.forEach(function(collName) {
    db.createCollection(collName, {autoIndexId: true});
});
```

I'm trying to cycle also some db but with this kind of code:

```
var dblist = ["emanueledb", "db_ema_dv"];
var collectionList = ["ab111", "bc111"];
dblist.forEach(function(dbname) { db.getSiblingDB(dbname)
        collectionList.forEach(function(collName) {
                db.createCollection(collName, {autoIndexId: true});
})
});
```

it works but create only the two collection on db_ema_dv. What is wrong?

Is also possible to get collection and db from an external csv to automate everything??

CSV example:

```
dbname,collectionname
emanueledb,collection1
emanueledb,collection2
testdb,testcollection
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted this expression does nothing (it selects the database but you don't do anything with the database):

```
db.getSiblingDB(dbname)
```

Try:

```
db.getSiblingDB(dbname).createCollection(collName, {autoIndexId: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, thank you! Now works!

```
    var dblist = ["emanueledb", "db_ema_dv"];
var collectionList = ["ab111111", "bc111111"];
dblist.forEach(function(dbname) { 
        collectionList.forEach(function(collName) {
                db.getSiblingDB(dbname).createCollection(collName, {autoIndexId: true});
})
});
```

as requested before, is possibile to get db and collection from a csv?

CSV Example:

```
dblist,collectionList
emanueledb,collection1
emanueledb,collection2
testdb,testcollection
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a database from a .csv you can use the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) command. This will read a CSV file into a collection.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, but if i inderstood mongoimport import data from a csv into a db. I mean if is possible, to get variable from a csv to pass into a .js script(the script that i posted) to create a new dbs and new collections or a new collections to existing db without writing the variables in the script.

Comment: Not with mongoimport. It expects a file and has on interpolation support.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you make an example if possible? Thx

Comment: Meant to say has "no interpolation" support. You could insert the docs with mongoimport and use the update command to change them to what you want. There is a full CRUD tutorial for node.js at https://developer.mongodb.com/quickstart/node-crud-tutorial.